# Utility of QZSS over India

Tags: gps

I have noticed with two mobile devices (Samsung S2+ and OnePlus 5) that the GNSS sensor picks up QZSS satellites (PRN 193 and 194 [only for OnePlus 5]), even while using these devices over Northern parts of India. Strangely, I have not picked up these satellites with some dedicated GPS receivers (Garmin GPS12, Garmin GPSMap 78s and Magellan GPS315) and even some mobile devices (Motorola Defy+, Motorola Moto G3, Nexus 7C, Nexus 7 2013), where as the QZSS signal is supposed to be compatible with traditional GPS.

This [webpage](http://qzss.go.jp/en/overview/services/sv02_why.html) (official, I think) shows a graphical depiction of `Main area where QZSS is avalable` as:

[image]

So, is/are there any utility of my device picking up QZSS satellites even while being in Northern parts of India?

Comment: There are ground segments to QZSS to some areas in India http://www.navipedia.net/index.php/QZSS#QZSS_System_description

Comment: page 5 shows coverage in India http://www.unoosa.org/pdf/icg/2010/ICG5/18october/06bis.pdf